# Setting windows credentials for integrated security in jdbc (& hibernate)

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Apologies if this has been answered many times before.  So far I've seen quite a few "no you can't do this" answers around but they have all been at least 5 years old so I thought I'd venture the question...

I am writing a java web (intranet) app which will connect to a MS SQL Server (2012) database.  In initial development I have connected with SQL Server security and also with integrated security and written and read from the db so I about to move on.  Our databases are maintained by a dba team though and our .net apps set specific windows credentials so that only one user is set up on the database.  I think they prefer this.  I was wondering if it is possible to set the windows credentials from Java ?  So for example

jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://servername;database=dbname;integratedSecurity=true;

would connect as domain\appuser ?

I guess I can use active directory groups for this so it's not a vital issue but I was curious!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can supply credentials to the SQL Server JDBC driver. You can also use the web client's identity which is what I think you are really asking. This is called "delegation" and the Kerberos protocol supports that.

But you would have to authenticate the web client using Kerberos and the service account (the account used by your web service to participate in Kerberos authentication with clients) would have to permit delegation. Then, during authentication, you would have to store the delegated credential in the Kebreros credential cache so that when you try to use the SQL Server JDBC driver, it can see it and use it as the connecting identity.

But to be honest, even though this seems like an elegant way to do this, you should probably not use delegation. Not for HTTP applications. In practice, Kerberos is rather fickle. And I'm not aware of a really good package for authenticating web clients using Kerberos in Java. They're out there. But they're hackish. The Kerberos implementation built into Java is not very good. For example, Kerberos relies heavily on DNS but the builtin Java Kerberos just uses Java's DNS which defaults to the host DNS which means it has very limited abilities (cannot query different DNS servers). Also, if you use the clients identity to connect to SQL server, you are going to be creating and tearing down a lot of expensive DB connections. Meaning it will be slow. It might look like it will work, but if you really put it under load, it will be noticeably slow.

So what I'm saying is that you should really just use the one identity to connect to SQL Server. This is the "industry best practice" at this point. Don't use delegation unless you absolutely need it.

Comment: Thanks.  In very broad terms where would I supply the credentials ?  Do I set up a dummy network user in the code and call using that or Is it a set of properties on the connection, or in the connections string (connection.user, .domain, password etc.